# Using require('babel/register') vs. transpiling the code before running

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

Are there any performance benefits of the latter compared to the former? When I tested it on my own, the time it took for one of my projects to load already transpiled was much shorter than when it uses babel/register. Apart from start-up time though, I'm not entirely sure what I'd write to benchmark the two fairly. Does anyone know whether the overhead Babel adds is just from babel/register transpiling code as it's running, or is it slow no matter what you do?

Comment: my assumption would be *"is just from babel/register transpiling code as it's running"* to test, run the same code twice. The second time through should be faster, due to it only having to transpile it on first require().

Comment: Do you mean requiring babel/register twice? It only needs to be required once in the main file to transpile all of the scripts that get required, as far as I know.

Comment: Yes, that's my point. The transpile only happens once, per run. if you omit that from your test adn just test the speed of the logic that the module returns, you can test whether or not there is a performance difference. If you just look at overall time (including the transpile time during require()) the pre-transpile will always win because it runs once before all runs, rather than once before each run.

Comment: In other words, build a sample module that returns a collection of methods, then test the speed of said methods in both scenarios.

Comment: I guess, the point i'm making is that there are two things you're testing here: the output of each transpile method, and then the benefits of transpiling up front vs inline. Up front will always be faster in production because you can transpile it in dev and never have to deal with it in production, where as inline *might* be faster during development because it's one less step in the build process.

Comment: I've opted to use inline, and only plan to re-evaluate that if a performance problem arises. Until then, i'd consider worrying about it a premature optimization.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in that it affects startup time (it will drastically, depending on how large your project is). As for actual runtime, it should make exactly 0 difference unless there is a bug in Node itself (which would sadly not likely to be fixed, since it's deprecated).